# How to find the maximum depth of a list in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a function that returns the maximum 'depth' of a list. If the list contains no other lists within it, it should return 1. If the list contains at most one list within it, it should return 2. If it has at most two list within a list in it, it should return 3, and so on.

Example:

```py
depth_one = [1, 2, 3]  # should return 1
depth_two = [1, [2], 3] # should return 2
depth_three = [1, [[2], 3], [4]] # should return 3
```

I was thinking of using a recursive algorithm, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how does `numpy` relate to this question?

Comment: "I was thinking of using a recursive algorithm, but I couldn't figure it out." Well, are you able to write a recursive algorithm *at all*? What are the steps that you should take in order to work out a recursive algorithm? What happens when you try following those steps, and writing out your understanding of the necessary process - using a real pen or pencil on paper?

Comment: I was trying to use numpy.shape to get the shape of this lists, but apparently this doesn't work on this type of lists.

Comment: "but apparently this doesn't work on this type of lists." Well, yes; this data *doesn't have* a "shape" in the sense that Numpy means. Numpy data **must** have the same length in each dimension, at each point in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to express this recursively is that the depth of a list is equal to one plus the depth of its deepest sublist.

Hence:

```
>>> def depth(arr):
...     if not isinstance(arr, list):
...         return 0
...     return 1 + max(depth(i) for i in arr)
...
>>> depth([1, 2, 3])
1
>>> depth([1, [2], 3])
2
>>> depth([1, [[2], 3], [4]])
3
```

Comment: This is the most pythonic way, but one could also count the max of '[' minus ']'.

Comment: What if one of the list elements is the string `"[[[[[[["`?

Comment: that is a good point.